# How to delete etc folder from WEB-INF classes folder using maven?

Tags: maven, maven-3

We have a very old project in ant which we are converting into maven. In old project we do have etc folder which is having some properties and some other files which are require for deployment. My requirement is to copy from etc folder all required files based on different profiles but the WEB-INF->classes folder should not contain etc folder. Our project's pom.xml (not pasting whole) is below but with that etc folder is not getting removed :

```
   <groupId>com.text.cm</groupId>
    <artifactId>cm-ws</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id></build.profile.id>
                <build.profile.properties.id></build.profile.properties.id>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>-prod</build.profile.id>
                <build.profile.properties.id>_prod</build.profile.properties.id>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        </profiles>
        <build>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>/src/main/resources/etc</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/web.xml</include>
                                        <include>**/cm-servlet.xml</include>
                                        <include>**/jboss-web.xml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>etc/**</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>
                                        ../text-cm-jboss/src/main/resources/datasources
                                    </directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>cm-db2-ds${build.profile.id}.xml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                 <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF/classes/properties
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>/src/main/resources/etc/properties/</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>
                                            environment${build.profile.properties.id}.properties
                                        </include>
                                        <include>
                                            cm.properties
                                        </include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources-2</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF/classes/xml
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>/src/main/resources/etc/xml/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-resources</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF/classes
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>/src/main/resources/</directory>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>etc/**</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

The etc directory is being copied because it is located under default resource directory.

You are copying resource using goal `copy-resources` as per your need which is great. But the default `resources` goal is also executed automatically at the same time and that's why you are seeing etc folder under classes.

One thing I would do , in this context, is exclude all directories and files from default resources directory so that whenever `resources` goal is run automatically, nothing is copied.

For eg,

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
      <directory>src/resources</directory>     
      <excludes>
          <exclude>**</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: What will be the phase and goal for this snippet?

Comment: if i include above code i am getting this error : Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode

Comment: That error is normal for war packaging and when the web.xml is not found under expected directory. Did you try putting web.xml under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`?

Comment: Due to that only i am copying that from etc folder using copy-resources. I can't change the existing structure of project ... my requirement is with copy-resources is it possible that etc folder will not be included in WEB-INF->classes folder

Comment: I would rather try and a very basic web.xml which might only have namespace declaration. Just to pass the Maven packing.